# Child Theme Issue - activated but does not show in preview

Tags: child-theme

I created a lot child-themes but with a specific theme it doesn't seem to work for some reason... I can't figure it out...

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: theme1369-child
Theme URI: http://mallkungen.se/wordpress-mallar-type/36148.html
Description: A child theme of theme1369
Author: Mercury
Author URI: http://mallkungen.se/search?author=210
Version: 1.0.0
Template: theme1369
*/
@import url("../theme1369/style.css");
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

/* custom jquery */
function jquery_stuff() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'init', 'jquery_stuff');
```

The issue is that the child-theme is showing up correctly in admin, but when previewing (or activing) the theme nothing is shown (white page) and console in chrome says its just failed from server.

I've also tested creating an empty functions.php but there are / is no difference.

Comment: `Function` should be `function`

Comment: @PieterGoosen - what do you mean?

Comment: I see the problem is corrected in edits :-). If you tested the child theme without functions.php and just with style.css and you still have this issue, contact the theme author. Some code in the parent theme is causing this issue then

Comment: @PieterGoosen - ok :-) I've tested without functions.php as well and same issue. Ok thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Just one note, do not add `jquery` to `init`. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts`